# How to get url of current window when using Facebook Unity sdk

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-canvas, facebook-unity-sdk

I tried calling:

```
Application.ExternalEval("UnityObject2.instances[0].getUnity().SendMessage('GameObjectName', 'SomeFunctionHere', document.URL);");
```

Which works great, but it could only retrieve the frame's url (it is a very long random html link) instead of the outer top most like https://apps.facebook.com/appnamehere. I also tried window.top.location.href but it gives me a security error since it wasn't allowed.

I need to process the url before I even init, so I cannot use fb's deeplink or anything like that. Any ideas on how to get the url? I'm using 5.0.4 of the SDK on Facebook Canvas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of cross-domain security, it isn't possible to get the top url.

Comment: So there is no way to get the browser's url at all?

Comment: As far as I know, if the outer iframe is on a different domain, you cannot get its url from an inner iframe because of those security reasons.